# Reverting Security Patch via Cronjob .. Possible?

Tags: cron, security, patches

On my server, I have always used a quick one use cronjob to apply the magento patches, as I don't have access to SSH. It worked fine, however with this new patch that has come out (SUPEE-6482), it is requesting to revert patch SUPEE-6285 and apply the new one. I tried reverting via the cronjob by just running it again, and I get this:

```
Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...
ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully.

patching file app/Mage.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n] 
Apply anyway? [n] 
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file app/Mage.php.rej
patching file app/code/community/Phoenix/Moneybookers/controllers/MoneybookersController.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n] 
Apply anyway? [n] 
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/community/Phoenix/Moneybookers/controllers/MoneybookersController.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n] 
Apply anyway? [n] 
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/AjaxController.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n] 
Apply anyway? [n] 
Skipping patch.

And so on...
```

So my question, is if this is possible to be done this way, and if not, what other means would there be to revert the patch without using SSH?

-- NOTE --

I have already gotten one tip, stating:

```
You should be able to revert the patch also by calling it via cron, you just need to add a -R to the command so if your cron job command was:

30 3 * * * sh /var/www/webserver/patch.sh

then to revert use the cronjob command

30 3 * * * sh /var/www/webserver/patch.sh -R
```

However, my control panel does not allow for that kind of customization, it simply asks for a time and the file, not leaving room to even add the '-R', so my thinking is that is it possible within the patch to have it run through the processes and when it asks 'Assume -R?' .. have it marked yes instead of no?

Answer (score 1):

This is really really not what I would recommend but if you need to run a file, there are two ways:

**Method 1: Create another .sh file to run your patch.sh file**
Let's name it `revert.sh`.

The content of that file could be:

```
#!/bin/sh
./var/www/webserver/patch.sh -R
```

Put your revert.sh into your crontab configuration.

**Method 2: Create a PHP file to run your patch.sh file**

Create a PHP file which you can run from the crontab (for example `revert.php`).

Content of this file:

```
shell_exec('/var/www/webserver/patch.sh -R');
```

**Make sure that this file does not lie within your DocumentRoot and that it cannot be run from outside.**